# Replace part of the string

Tags: php, string, replace, ip, strip

Echo `$var` gives me something like `http://342.234.243.142/data/somethingmore/`

IP-address everytime is different.
Instead of "somethingmore" can something like "/folder/images/2011/gallery/file.jpg" (anything)

How do I strip from this string part with the ip and /data/ folder?

`$var` could become `/somethingmore/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://342.234.243.142/data/somethingmore/';
echo basename($url);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "http://342.234.243.142/data/somethingmore/";
$str = explode('/', $str);

print_r($str);
```

Comment: @Messi: You should make it more clear what part of URL do you needs? your edit is confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression:

```
/.*?\/data/
```

This way you can get a full string after '/data' even if it contains more '/' (slashes). For example, `http://342.234.243.142/data/somethingmore/andmore/`