# PHP RegEx/Substring to get ID from a string

Tags: php

Here is my string:

```
**tag:my.domain.com,2011-07-13:/895645783/posts/NHg5XdqFb5b/**
```

I want to take the last section **/NHg5XdqFb5b/** and remove the slashes.

Also are there any tools available to attemtp to work this out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662777/replace-part-of-the-string/6662803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by:

```
<?php
    $id = explode("/", "**tag:my.domain.com,2011-07-13:/895645783/posts/NHg5XdqFb5b/**");
    $myID = $id[count($id)-2]; 
?>
```

Or if you want to use regex: (make sure all ids are 11 in length)

```
preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}/i", "**tag:my.domain.com,2011-07-13:/895645783/posts/NHg5XdqFb5b/**", $matches);
echo($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a preg_replace http://ch.php.net/preg_replace

```
$var = preg_replace('~.*/([^/]+)/\*\*~','$1',$var);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode, which will split the string and return an array

```
$arr = explode("/", your_string_here); //split string by "/"
$id = $arr[count($arr) - 2]; //in your case, get the second-last part
```

Alternatively,

```
$arr = preg_match("\/posts\/(.*?)\/", your_string_here); //matches /posts/NHg5XdqFb5b/
//$arr[0] = whole match
//$arr[1] = 1st capture group (part between brackets) in your regex, i.e. required id
$id = $arr[1];
```

Cheers,